# Tensorflow tf_strided_slice elaboration

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to understand how tf.strided_slice works. In order to do this, I've written the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# parameters
record_size = 841

# create a random vector of 1682 integers in range [0.255]
content = np.random.randint(255,size=[1682])

depth_major = tf.reshape(
  tf.strided_slice(content, [0],
                   [record_size]),
                   [1, 29, 29])

depth_major1 = tf.reshape(
  tf.strided_slice(content, [record_size+1],
                   [2*record_size]),
                   [1, 29, 29])

# Initializing the variables
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session as sess:
  sess.run(depth_major)
  print("depth_major", depth_major.shape)
```

When I execute the above example, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Cannot reshape a tensor with 840 elements to shape [1,29,29] (841 elements) for 'Reshape_1' (op: 'Reshape') with input shapes: [840], [3] and with input tensors computed as partial shapes: input[1] = [1,29,29].
```

I simply cannot understand why the number of elements is 840 since I start at [0] and end at [record_size]?

Answer (score 0):

The error is complaining about the *second* `Reshape`. You can see this since the `Reshape` name is `Reshape_1` in the error message. The `strided_slice` in the second reshape goes from `record_size+1` to `2*record_size` which is size `1682 - 842 = 840`. Thus the error message about the wrong size. I think you want to specify `record_size` instead of `record_size+1`.

Hope that helps!